# Can one print the QualType of function pointers with a name using Clang AST?

Tags: c++, clang, function-pointers, clang++, llvm-clang

Is there any easy and reliable way (a.k.a. not regex) to get the `QualType` of a function pointer declaration as a string but with a name attached to it? I tried looking into leveraging `QualType::getAsString(const PrintingPolicy &Policy)`, but unfortunately, there is no option with that configuration.

e.g.

`int (*)(void)` ----> `int (*whatever_name_here)(void)`

Comment: Have you looked into the [printing policy](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structclang_1_1PrintingPolicy.html) parameter you can provide? (in particular, the FullyQualifiedName member)

Answer (score 0):

You can create [`VarDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html) and print that.

Assuming `ctx` is your [`ASTContext`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTContext.html) and `type` is your `QualType`, here is what you can do:

```
// Create identifier.
IdentifierInfo id = ctx.Idents.get("whatever_name_here");
// Create variable declaration.
VarDecl *vd = VarDecl::Create(ctx, ctx.getTranslationUnitDecl(), 
    SourceLocation(), SourceLocation(), &id, type, nullptr, StorageClass:SC_None);
// Print it.
vd->print(/* put your llvm::raw_stream here */, ctx.getPrintingPolicy());
```